# My problem with get duration between 2 dates via moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

there are two dates with a difference of 20 minutes:

```
const a = moment.tz('Europe/Kiev');
const b = moment(item.sheduledAt);
console.log('my current time: ', a.format('DD MMMM, HH:mm')); // 08 June, 09:42
console.log('sheduled time: ', b.format('DD MMMM, HH:mm')) // 08 June, 10:00
console.log('diff: ', b.diff(a)) // 11832381
console.log('dur: ', moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asHours()) // 3.2867725
```

If you do not specify the time zone, then my time is shown incorrectly (according to the real server, it is 3 hours less). But after all, I'm just comparing 2 dates, which, when using format () above, show a difference of 20 minutes, where does 3 hours come from and how to remove them?

Comment: You did not specified time zone for `b`, only for `a`

Comment: Thanks, I have not correct save in DB

Comment: timezone was not taken into account when saving the form, strange. everything seemed to be correct: this.setState({scheduleDate: moment(scheduleDate).tz(user.timezone)}); this.state.sheduleDate.set({h:e.target.value})

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've posted an answer considering your comment if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem saving the date so that it is set correctly and is "the same" for everyone given the timezone:

I have a 3 step date and time picker. First you use the calendar('react-day-picker'), then set the hours and minutes to the given date, looks like this:

```
(pickerData) => this.setState({sheduleDate: moment(pickerData).tz('Europe/Kiev')});
(e) => this.setState({sheduleDate: this.state.sheduleDate.set({h: e.target.value})});
(e) => this.setState({sheduleDate: this.state.sheduleDate.set({m: e.target.value})})
// submit form - pseudocode
() => data['sheduledAt'] = moment(sheduleDate).unix() * 1000; // this is where I did not specify tz() for moment(sheduleDate) and got the server time, if I understand correctly
```

When specifying tz(), the date is then read correctly for all timezones, i.e. if I have an event in 20 minutes, then it is in 20 minutes in both the USA and Ukraine.

Big thanks to Justinas for help!